# How to add extensions to Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I an trying to figure out how to add webRequest extension to Microsoft Edge. Can someone provide some assistance? I have gone though a number of documents, but when I go to Microsoft online store I don't see it there.

Test code:

```
<html> 
<script>
    browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    logURL,
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }
);
function logURL(requestDetails) {
    console.log("Loading: " + requestDetails.url);
};
</script>  
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "webRequest extension"? Is there such an extension existing? If you want to add an online extension to Edge, you could search it in Microsoft online store. If the search result is none, then it doesn't exist. If you want to load an extension developed by yourself, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/adding-and-removing-extensions).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis

Comment: webRequest is an API of Edge extension, it certainly can't be found in Microsoft online store. You could use it when you develop Edge extensions. You could find the  usage of webRequest in [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest).

Comment: Do I need to install any extension to Edge to make it work?

Comment: No, you needn't. You could use it directly in your code.

Comment: So, code like browser.webRequest ....   should work right away?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Here is the error running it in Edge: Unable to get property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined or null reference. And here is the code: browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest. browser object exists, but it doesn't have webRequest.

Comment: It could be better you provide a [minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue. So that we can have a better understanding of the issue and test it on our sides. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Added test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc of [webRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) in MDN, we can see that:

> To use the webRequest API for a given host, an extension must have the "webRequest" [API permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#API_permissions) and the [host permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions) for that host.

Where can we add the permissions? The answer is the `manifest.json` file. It is the necessary part of an extension. You could see the [Anatomy of an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) to learn the compositions of an extension.

Besides, `browser.webRequest` isn't in the list of [content scripts APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#WebExtension_APIs), so we can only use it in [background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts).

In a conclusion, we can't just use the `browser.webRequest` in a script of a html file. If we want to test the event `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, we need to have a `manifest.json` file, put permisssions in it:

```
"permissions": [
"*://learn.microsoft.com/*",
"webRequest"
]
```

Then put the scripts you gave in the background scripts. Then you could try to debug the extension in Edge, there will be no error. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/creating-an-extension) is an article about creating a Microsoft Edge extension, you could refer to it if you need.